# Integral of Bessel function, power, and hyperbolic cosecant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, special-functions, bessel-functions

I have the integral

$$
I(a)=\int\limits_0^\infty dk \ \frac{k^3J_1(ak)}{\sinh(k )}
$$

Where $J_1$ is a [Bessel function of the first kind](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2). By plotting the integrand, it seems $I(a)$ *exists* as the integrand is finite and goes to zero for large $k$. **I wonder if $I(a)$ may be expressed in `common' special functions**? Mathematica does not evaluate it, and I have been unable to find it in Gradshtein.

I have been able to find an approximation to $I(a)$ as $a \to 0$ by replacing $J_1$ with its asymptotic form for small argument. Unfortunately, in my application the interesting case is $a\to \infty$. **If $I(a)$ cannot be simplified, how can we develop an approximation to it for large $a$**?

Background: The integral arises in a Laplacian boundary value problem for the induced charge on a grounded plate.

Comment: Expanding the bessel function as a series and integrating gives a sum of polylogarithms, so maybe not.

Comment: what hinders you to use the asymptotics for large $a$?

Comment: @asgeige Initially when I did that I found *incorrectly* that the result did not approach (the numerical evaluation of) $I(a)$ for sufficiently large $a$. Following your comment I looked at it again and, yes it does work. Thank you!

Comment: @Sal Would it be useful to you if I added the asymptotics to my answer below?

Comment: @Gary Thank you. Using the sums in your answer I have arrived at $I \sim  \frac{3a}{(1+a^2)^{5/2}}$, by making the replacements $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \to \frac{a}{2}\int\limits_{1/a}^\infty dt$, and $t=\frac{2n+1}{a}$. If you have another method I would be pleased to hear it

Comment: @Sal I added the leading-order asymptotics to my answer below.

Comment: @Gary Much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: very interesting and challenging question !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we are trying to find the following integral:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right):=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\text{n}\mathscr{J}_1\left(\alpha x\right)}{\sinh\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x=\int_0^\infty x^\text{n}\mathscr{J}_1\left(\alpha x\right)\text{csch}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Using the 'evaluating integrals over the positive real axis' [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\int_0^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[x^\text{n}\mathscr{J}_1\left(\alpha x\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_x^{-1}\left[\text{csch}\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\space\text{d}\sigma\tag2$$

Using known results, we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial^\text{n}}{\partial\sigma^\text{n}}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+\sigma\left(\sigma+\sqrt{\alpha^2+\sigma^2}\right)}\right)\cdot\left(2\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\delta\left(\sigma-2\text{k}-1\right)\right)\space\text{d}\sigma\tag3$$

We can rewrite this a bit:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=2\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial^\text{n}}{\partial\sigma^\text{n}}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+\sigma\left(\sigma+\sqrt{\alpha^2+\sigma^2}\right)}\right)\cdot\delta\left(\sigma-2\text{k}-1\right)\space\text{d}\sigma\tag4$$

Using the property:

$$\int_0^\infty\text{y}\left(x\right)\delta\left(x-\text{p}\right)\space\text{d}x=\text{y}\left(\text{n}\right)\theta\left(\text{n}\right)\tag5$$

We can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=2\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\left\{\theta\left(1+2\text{k}\right)\cdot\left.\frac{\partial^\text{n}}{\partial\sigma^\text{n}}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+\sigma\left(\sigma+\sqrt{\alpha^2+\sigma^2}\right)}\right)\right|_{\space\sigma\space=\space1+2\text{k}}\right\}\tag6$$

Now, using the fact that when $\text{k}\in\mathbb{N}$ we get $\theta\left(1+2\text{k}\right)=1$. So we can conclude:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=2\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\left\{\left.\frac{\partial^\text{n}}{\partial\sigma^\text{n}}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+\sigma\left(\sigma+\sqrt{\alpha^2+\sigma^2}\right)}\right)\right|_{\space\sigma\space=\space1+2\text{k}}\right\}\tag7$$

Answer (score 5):

By [$(10.22.49)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E49) and [$(15.4.19)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E19) in the DLMF, we find
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^3 }}{{\sinh t}}J_1 (at)dt}  = 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^3 e^{ - t} \frac{1}{{1 - e^{ - 2t} }}J_1 (at)dt} 
\\ & = 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^3 \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {e^{ - (2n + 1)t} } J_1 (at)dt} \\ & = 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^3 } e^{ - (2n + 1)t} J_1 (at)dt} 
\\ & = 24a\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2n + 1)^5 }}F\!\left( {\frac{5}{2},3;2; - \frac{{a^2 }}{{(2n + 1)^2 }}} \right)} 
\\ & = 24a\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {(2n + 1)^2  - \frac{{a^2 }}{4}} \right)\frac{1}{{((2n + 1)^2  + a^2 )^{7/2} }}} \\ &=
24a\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{((2n + 1)^2  + a^2 )^{5/2} }}}  - 30a^3 \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{((2n + 1)^2  + a^2 )^{7/2} }}} 
\end{align*}
provided $\Re a>0$. Here $F$ stands for the hypergeometric function.

**Addendum.** I shall give the asymptotics for $a\to +\infty$. Let us introduce the *generalised Mathieu series* via
$$
S_{\mu ,\gamma } (a;\lambda ) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{n^\gamma  }}{{(n^\lambda   + a^\lambda  )^\mu  }}} \quad \quad (\mu  > 0,\quad \lambda  > 0,\quad \lambda \mu  - \gamma  > 1).
$$
With this notation
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{((2n + 1)^2  + a^2 )^\mu  }}}  = S_{\mu ,0} (a;2) - 4^{ - \mu } S_{\mu ,0} (a/2;2) 
$$
provided $\mu>\frac{1}{2}$. The precise asymptotics of the generalised Mathieu series was derived in [this paper](https://www.longdom.org/articles/exponentially-small-expansions-associated-with-a-generalised-mathieu-series.pdf). In particular,
$$
S_{\mu ,0} (a;2) = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  \Gamma \left( {\mu  - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}{{2\Gamma (\mu )a^{2\mu  - 1} }} - \frac{1}{{2a^{2\mu } }} + \frac{{\pi ^\mu  }}{{\Gamma (\mu )a^\mu  }}e^{ - 2\pi a} (1 + o(1))
$$
as $a\to +\infty$. Consequently,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{((2n + 1)^2  + a^2 )^\mu  }}}  = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  \Gamma \left( {\mu  - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}{{4\Gamma (\mu )a^{2\mu  - 1} }} - \frac{{\pi ^\mu  }}{{\Gamma (\mu )(2a)^\mu  }}e^{ - \pi a} (1 + o(1))
$$
as $a\to +\infty$. Combining this with the exact series representation above, we find
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^3 }}{{\sinh t}}J_1 (at)dt}  =
\frac{{\sqrt 2 \,\pi ^3 }}{{a^{1/2} }}e^{ - \pi a} (1 + o(1))
$$
as $a\to +\infty$. More precise asymptotics can be derived by using more terms in the asymptotic expansion of the generalised Mathieu series which can be found in the paper cited above.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more self contained approach.

We rewrite the integral in terms of [Hankel functions $H_1(x)$ of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Hankel_functions:_H(1)%CE%B1,_H(2)%CE%B1) since they have the nice property of [decaying exponentially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms) in the upper half of the complex plane. By Lemma 1 proven below, we get:
$$
I(a)=\frac12\Re\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{k^3 H_{1}(ak)}{\sinh(k)}dk =\frac12\Re \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)
$$

Now due to the above mentioned decay, we close the contour of integration in the upper half plane and get by residue theorem
$$
I(a)=\Re(\pi i \sum_{k>0} \text{res}(g(z),z=i \pi k) )
$$

it is worth noting that since $x^3H_1(x)$ has no poles in the complex plane we only sum over the zeros of $\sinh(x)$.
In the asymptotic limit of large $a$ only the residue which is closest to the imaginary axis will contribute to lowest order (additional terms are suppressed by $O(e^{- k \pi a })$)

$$
I(a)\sim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\Re(\pi i  \text{res}(g(z),z=i \pi ) )=\Re(-\pi^4 H_{1}(i a \pi))
$$

by the standard asymptotic expansions for the Hankel function this is equivalent to

> $$
> I(a)\sim_{a\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\pi^3\sqrt{2}e^{-\pi a}}{\sqrt a}\left(1+\frac{3}{ 8 a \pi}+o(a^{-1})\right)
> $$

which coincides with the other answer to leading order. I expect this technique to work for every $k^l H_{\nu}(a k)$ such that $l,\nu  \in 2\mathbb{N}+1$ or $l,\nu  \in 2\mathbb{N}$.

**Lemma 1:**

$\Re(H_{\nu}(x))$ is even for $\nu \in 2\mathbb{N}+1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$

**Proof:**
$$
\Re(H_{\nu}(x)) = \begin{cases}
  -J_{\nu}(x)  & x <0 \\
  J_{\nu}(x) & x>0
\end{cases}
$$

the first case follows from the [connection formula 10.4.7](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.4) and $J_{\nu}(-x)=e^{i\pi \nu}J_{\nu}(x)$.
the second case is due to the very definiton of the Hankel function for $x>0$. Since $J_{\nu}(x)$ is odd, we are done. **QED**

Comment: This is a great answer; thank you!